# Percona 5.6 installs mysql 5.7 why?

Tags: percona

I installed Percona server 5.6.

Installation notes:

```
{"homebrew_version":"1.1.11-103-g52d1d2c","used_options":[],"unused_options":["--with-test","--with-embedded","--with-memcached","--with-local-infile"],"built_as_bottle":true,"poured_from_bottle":true,"installed_as_dependency":false,"installed_on_request":true,"changed_files":["bin/msql2mysql","bin/mysql_config","bin/mysqlbug","bin/mysqld_multi","bin/mysqld_safe","libexec/mysqlaccess","sql-bench/crash-me","sql-bench/server-cfg","support-files/mysql.server","support-files/mysqld_multi.server","INSTALL_RECEIPT.json","homebrew.mxcl.percona-server@5.6.plist","include/mysql/my_config.h","mysql-test/Makefile","mysql-test/suite/ndb/include/have_java.inc","share/doc/percona-server@5.6/INFO_BIN","share/man/man1/myisam_ftdump.1","share/man/man1/mysql.server.1","share/man/man1/mysql_config.1","share/man/man1/mysqlaccess.1","share/man/man1/mysqld_multi.1","share/man/man1/mysqld_safe.1","support-files/mysql-log-rotate"],"time":1490089577,"source_modified_time":1476356576,"HEAD":null,"stdlib":"libcxx","compiler":"clang","runtime_dependencies":[{"full_name":"openssl","version":"1.0.2k"}],"source":{"path":"/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/percona-server@5.6.rb","tap":"homebrew/core","spec":"stable","versions":{"stable":"5.6.33-79.0","devel":null,"head":null,"version_scheme":0}}}
```

when I check the version in mysql it shows 5.7

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.7.17                |
| protocol_version        | 10                    |
| slave_type_conversions  |                       |
| tls_version             | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 |
| version                 | 5.7.17                |
| version_comment         | Homebrew              |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                |
| version_compile_os      | osx10.11              |
+-------------------------+-----------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What command did you use to install? This is most likely a homebrew issue.

Comment: Yes I used home brew to instal it

Comment: This has been verified as a Homebrew issue. Try doing 'brew install percona-server@5.6'

Comment: I have used brew `install percona-server@5.6` but its still same problem

Comment: Not for me it doesn't.


 [drmac@othala ~]$ brew install percona-server@5.6
 Updating Homebrew...
 ==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
 Updated Homebrew from f9e8d84 to 1ef00aa.
 ...
 ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/percona-server@5.6-5.6.35-81.0.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
 ==> Pouring percona-server@5.6-5.6.35-81.0.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
 ...
 [drmac@othala ~]$ /usr/local/opt/percona-server@5.6/bin/mysqld --version
 /usr/local/opt/percona-server@5.6/bin/mysqld  Ver 5.6.35-81.0 for osx10.12 on x86_64 (Homebrew)

Comment: Evidence: https://www.hastebin.com/raw/inusotevew

Answer (score 0):

The brew formula is fixed. This should not occure again. I tested and it installed mysql 5.6